# spring security + angular js login returns 404

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to spring security and trying to perform login using spring security but when i clink login button in login page, it shows 404 error.
     I am using angular js for frontend.
     My login action is /user/login which i am calling from login_service.js.
     Below is spring configuration files.

```
web.xml
---------

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">

    <display-name>CCUAPP</display-name>
    <description>Credit Card Application</description>

    <!-- For web context -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ccuapp-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ccuapp-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- For root context -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-core-config.xml</param-value>      
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>dev</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>

spring-mvc-config.xml
=====================

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">

    <!-- **************************************************************** -->
    <!-- SPRING ANNOTATION PROCESSING -->
    <!-- **************************************************************** -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nfdil.ccuapp.web" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/static/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/LableResources</value>
                <value>/WEB-INF/MessageResources</value>
            </list>
       </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>  

    <!-- **************************************************************** -->
    <!-- RESOURCE FOLDERS CONFIGURATION -->
    <!-- Dispatcher configuration for serving static resources -->
    <!-- **************************************************************** -->

    <mvc:resources location="/static/" mapping="/static/**" />  
</beans>

SecurityConfiguration.java



@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity

public class SecurityConfiguration  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    private static String REALM="MY_TEST_REALM";
    public static final String UserListURL = "/getAllCompanies";
    public static final String loginURL = "/user/login";
    public static final String logoutURL = "/logout";
    public static final String getUploadTransURL = "/getAllTransactions";

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;



    @Autowired
    TokenBasedAuthenticationService tokenBasedAuthenticationService;

    @Autowired
    SuccessHandler successHandler;

    @Autowired
    FailureHandler failureHandler;

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
    .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginProcessingUrl(loginURL)
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .successHandler(successHandler)
        .failureHandler(failureHandler)
        .failureUrl(logoutURL)
        .permitAll()

    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .filterSecurityInterceptorOncePerRequest(true)
        .antMatchers(UserListURL).access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers(getUploadTransURL).permitAll()
    .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(getCustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(tokenBasedAuthenticationService),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        super.configure(http);

    }




    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter getCustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter() throws Exception{
        CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter customAuthenticationProcessingFilter = new CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter(loginURL);
        customAuthenticationProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        customAuthenticationProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler);
        customAuthenticationProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler);
        return customAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
    }
}


login_service.js

'use strict';

angular.module('myApp').factory('LoginService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){


    var factory = {
        login:login
    };

    return factory;

    function login(user) {
        var uploadUrl = "user/login";
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post(uploadUrl, {params:{username:user.userid,password:user.password}},{ headers : {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }})
            .then(
            function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            },
            function(errResponse){
                 console.info(' login submit'+errResponse);
                deferred.reject(errResponse);
            }
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    }

}]);
```

Please help what i am missing.

Comment: you get 404 in your xhr request?

Comment: when js post data in user/login url. it gives me 404 (Not Found) in browser console,

Comment: I get this log in java console o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/creditcard/user/login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'ccuapp-dispatcher'

Comment: I think you don't have /user/login requestmapping in your controller.

Comment: i have given /user/login in spring security configuration as login processing url. where should i set request mapping?